# Postgres сохранение промежуточного значения

Tags: postgresql

существующая проблема.
есть таблица, разбитая на партиции. хочу сделать выборку с использованием некоторого значения (конкретно - время начала смены).

но видимо получается запрос к партиции с временем каждый раз когда запрос делает выборку (т.е. значения starting.starting извлекаются для каждой партиции)

есть ли возможность указать Postgres что эти значения не нужно выбирать каждый раз (закэшировать на время выполнения вопроса, что ли)

```
SELECT tag.*
FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" tag,
  (SELECT "ID_TagData",
          "F_Date" AS starting,
           MAX ("F_ConvertedValue")
   FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
   WHERE "F_TagName_ID"=87
     AND "F_Date" > TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 7:50:00'
     AND "F_Date" < TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 8:10:00'
   GROUP BY "F_Date",
            "ID_TagData"
   ORDER BY "F_Date" DESC LIMIT 1) starting,
  (SELECT "ID_TagData",
          "F_Date" AS ending,
          MAX ("F_ConvertedValue")
   FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
   WHERE "F_TagName_ID"=87
     AND "F_Date" > TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 19:50:00'
     AND "F_Date" < TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 20:10:00'
   GROUP BY "F_Date",
            "ID_TagData"
   ORDER BY "F_Date" DESC LIMIT 1) ending
WHERE (tag."F_Date" > starting.starting
       AND tag."F_Date" <= TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 20:10:00')
  AND tag."F_TagName_ID"=87
  ORDER BY tag."F_Date" desc
```

план

https://vk.com/doc19953508_437262011

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "каждый раз". каждый подзапрос в from выполняется один раз. Лишний раз он его и так выполнять не должен

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте с инструкцией WITH:

```
WITH
    starting AS (
    SELECT  "ID_TagData", "F_Date" AS starting, MAX ("F_ConvertedValue")
    FROM    "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
    WHERE   "F_TagName_ID"=87
        AND "F_Date" > TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 7:50:00'
        AND "F_Date" < TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 8:10:00'
    GROUP BY "F_Date", "ID_TagData"
    ORDER BY "F_Date" DESC LIMIT 1),
    ending AS (
    SELECT  "ID_TagData", "F_Date" AS ending, MAX ("F_ConvertedValue")
    FROM    "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
    WHERE   "F_TagName_ID"=87
        AND "F_Date" > TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 19:50:00'
        AND "F_Date" < TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 20:10:00'
    GROUP BY "F_Date", "ID_TagData"
    ORDER BY "F_Date" DESC LIMIT 1)
SELECT tag.*
FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" tag, starting,  ending
WHERE   (tag."F_Date" > starting.starting AND tag."F_Date" <= TIMESTAMP'2016-02-4 20:10:00')
        AND tag."F_TagName_ID"=87
ORDER BY tag."F_Date" desc
```